# Excel Workbook connections field "Last refreshed" always empty

Tags: excel, connection-string

in Excel 2010, under Data-Connections where there is a list of all connections in the workbook, there is a field "Last Refreshed". This field is always empty for me. Microsoft says (http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-HA010342379.aspx) "If blank, then the connection has never been refreshed", but this is obviously not the case here, because we refresh the date quite often.

Any ideas please ?
Thanks Petr

Comment: Good question. Never noticed it before, but it doesnt do it on mine either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This page http://www.thecodecage.com/forumz/showthread.php?t=208462 claims

> ... the "Last Refreshed" field is **populated** in the dialog box for the
>   connections that are used as **data sources for pivot tables**, **BUT not**
>   for connections that are used as the source **for Tables**. If the
>   connection is used as a source for a Table the "last refreshed"
>   section is empty

Sounds a bit like a missing feature to me...

Comment: Wow, issues like this make me think Microsoft ask a 3 year old child to design their products behaviour for them!

Anyone know how to the view the "Last Refresh" time for a connection used as a source for Tables.